# Elements on review stat popup overlap window rectangle

Tags: bug, review, design, localization

On MSE (English):

> [image: mse]

On ruSO (Russian):

> [image: ruSO]

On jaSO (Japaneese):

> [image: jaSO]

On ptSO (Portuguese):

> [image: ptSO]

On esSO (Spanish):

> [image: esSO]

Also note that progress indicator (white/green line) is not centered between values (current, needed) at least when no review completed yet, i.e. zero count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The review pages have been changed. They don't show anymore those tooltips.

The review pages are similar to the following one.

> [image]

Only the progress toward the review limit is shown in those pages, without any tooltip.

The badge progress is shown in the *Stats* tab.

> [image]

Even in this case, no tooltip is shown for that progress.